# How to show only one record that contains the same field values in an APEX SOQL Query

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

Not sure the best way to ask this. But essentially I have a survey for instructors that a student submits during the mid-term. Each survey submission is of course a different record but the instructor and class would be the same. When querying results I only want to show one record for that teacher and class not multiple records from the same teacher and class. Here is an example:

```
//Instrustor        //Registered Course
Becky Gosky         English Composition                                         
Bobbie Strother     Developmental Psychology                                            
Bobbie Strother     Anatomy & Physiology                                            
Bruce Priddy        Developmental Psychology                                            
Christy Saladino    Developmental Psychology                                            
Christy Saladino    Developmental Psychology                                            
Christy Saladino    Developmental Psychology                                            
Christy Saladino    NCLEX Preparation
```

As you can see Bobbie teaches a class in Developmental Psychology and also in Anatomy and Physiology -- he has also received a survey review from a student in each.

Bruce Priddy teaches Developmental Psychology as well.

Christy teaches Developmental Psychology too and has received 3 survey reviews and all 3 records are visible. I only want to output one record not multiple records that have the same instructor name and registered course. The reason why is for report user ability. I want to then add into a wrapper class the total response count for a specific instructor and and specific course.

I tried using a set, map, wrapper, etc... But the issue is instructor's names will be used more than once and so will the courses. So a set would not help. Unless I create a list, add the set to the new list, then make conditional statements and add to the list only when conditions are met. That way seems promising but I have not been able to completely make it work. Mostly because there is a time when both the instuctor and the course are in the set so I can no longer make a condition. I am convinced there has to be an easy way to just only output a record once if there are specified field names the same. I just can't seem to find a way. So I am reaching out to my community. Here is the method I am using:

```
    public list<wrapper> getlistWrap(){
            wrap = new list<wrapper>();
            listSurveyData = new list<End_Of_Class_Survey__c>([SELECT Id,Question_1_Mid_Survey__c,Question_1B_Mid_Survey__c,Question_1A_MidSurvey__c,Instructor__c,Registered_Course__c from End_Of_Class_Survey__c ORDER BY Instructor__c]);
            listInstructors = new list<Instructor__c>([SELECT Id, Name FROM Instructor__c]);
            listClassName = new list<string>();
            instructorName = new list<string>(); 
            getClassName  = new set<string>();
            getInstructorName = new set<string>();
            count = 0;
            for(integer i = 0; listSurveyData.size() > i; i++){
                if(listSurveyData[i].Instructor__c != '' && listSurveyData[i].Instructor__c != null && listSurveyData[i].Registered_Course__c != '' && listSurveyData[i].Registered_Course__c != null ){
                     instructorName.add(listSurveyData[i].Instructor__c);
                     listClassName.add(listSurveyData[i].Registered_Course__c);
                } 
            }
            system.debug('***********listClassName:' + listClassName);
            system.debug('***********instructorName:' + instructorName);   
            for(count = 0; listClassName.size() > count; count++ ){
                wrap.add(new wrapper(instructorName[count], listClassName[count]));  
            }

            return wrap;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem can be resolved by using a Map  and using the combination of Instructor and Course as Key in the map.

Something like

```
Map <String, SurveyResult> newMap = new Map <String, SurveyResult>();
for (SurveyResult k : [Select Instructor,CourseName,Score from SurverResult])
{ String x = k.Instructor + k.CourseName;
newMap.put(x,k);
}
```

Comment: it'll solve unique combinations of instructor and course (apart from funny situations when somebody has last name like beginning of some course's name...) but what then? you have the map and you need to run through all keys (full scan) if you want to know what "this" instructor has. `Map<String, Set<String>>` looks more hardcore but also more useful I think.

Answer (score 0):

I see couple options here, experiment a bit and if needed - edit your question? Should give you some ideas...

I'm assuming that `End_Of_Class_Survey__c.Instructor__c` is a lookup but `End_Of_Class_Survey__c.Registered_Course__c` is just a text field, not a lookup? Doesn't matter much but still - if it's not the case you might want to tweak it a bit.

**Solve it 100% with SOQL**

Query similar to this should be very close to what you're after

```java
SELECT Instructor__r.Name, Registered_Course__c, COUNT(Id)
FROM End_Of_Class_Survey__c
GROUP BY Instructor__r.Name, Registered_Course__c
ORDER BY Instructor__r.Name, Registered_Course__c
LIMIT 200
```

Problem with that is "how many combinations might be there". Unless you add some WHERE filters to it I think around 2K distinct combinations Salesforce will complain ("*AggregateResult doesn't support queryMore*").

(not sure if you really need to know the count of surveys per teacher & class? I thought you're after just "this teacher has 3 courses")

**Solve it partially with SOQL**

You should be able to make a relational query (a JOIN if you're familiar with that concept from normal databases) to fetch header (Instructor) + related list of surveys.

```java
SELECT Id, Name,
    (SELECT Registered_Course__c FROM End_Of_Class_Surveys__r)
FROM Instructor__c
```

(you'll need to check what's the exact name of the relationship. Again - I didn't include any WHERE statements, not even "skip instructors who don't have any surveys yet")

Then something like this?

```java
for(Instructor__c i : [My SELECT statement ...]){
    Set<String> courses = new Set<String>();
    for(End_Of_Class_Survey__c s : i.End_Of_Class_Surveys__r){
        courses.add(Registered_Course__c); 
    }
    System.debug(i.Name + ' has ' + courses.size() + ' unique courses: ' + courses);
}
```

I think this solution might have some hiccups if instructor has lots of surveys to his/her name... Again - think about WHERE clauses.

**Brute force apex**

This concept is somewhere between my v.2 and what you were going for in the question. It should work well up to whatever's your SOQL rows limit (50K for normal context, up to 1 million if you have marked the page as readonly). It's also one where the LIMIT clause is easiest to apply to ensure it doesn't blow up*... But not using the query with relationship is not very salesforce-y way.

I'll throw the results into a `Map` where key is instructor's id (put Name if you want) and values is `Set` of (unique) course names for this instructor.

```java
Map<Id, Set<String>> instructorsAndCourses = new Map<Id, Set<String>>();
for(End_Of_Class_Survey__c s : [SELECT Instructor__c, Registered_Course__c
FROM End_Of_Class_Survey__c
LIMIT 50000]){
    if(instructorsAndCourses.containsKey(s.Instructor__c)){
        instructorsAndCourses.get(s.Instructor__c).add(s.Registered_Course__c);
    } else {
        instructorsAndCourses.put(s.Instructor__c, new Set<String>{s.Registered_Course__c});
    }
}
System.debug(JSON.serializePretty(instructorsAndCourses));
```

- whether you'd want the page to explode with clear error or display well but with unfinished results is something I can't decide for you :)

Comment: Wow man, thanks for the dedicated response. I will definitely look into these alternative options. I appreciate you providing different paths, this will really allow me several options to reach the scope of the project. Sadly the instructor is not a lookup, just a string. The only lookup we have on that object is the student__c field that looks up the Contact object.

Comment: Right... In the long run you should consider making instructors & courses as separate objects and then create Survey as a "junction object" (detail in a master-detail relation to both of these).Anyway - you should be able to adapt 1st (simplify the query to just use `Instructor__c`) or 3rd (make it a `Map<String, Set<String>>` rather than Id-based)... If you'll be stuck - edit your question and drop me a comment, I'll have a look.